# SQL Server splits A <> B into A < B OR A > B, yielding strange results if B is non-deterministic

Tags: sql-server, optimization

We have encountered an interesting issue with SQL Server. Consider the following repro example:

```
CREATE TABLE #test (s_guid uniqueidentifier PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO #test (s_guid) VALUES ('7E28EFF8-A80A-45E4-BFE0-C13989D69618');

SELECT s_guid FROM #test
WHERE s_guid = '7E28EFF8-A80A-45E4-BFE0-C13989D69618'
  AND s_guid <> NEWID();

DROP TABLE #test;
```

[fiddle](http://rextester.com/REASM51008)

Please forget for a moment that the `s_guid <> NEWID()` condition seems entirely useless - this is just a minimal repro example. Since the probability of `NEWID()` matching some given constant value is extremely small, it should evaluate to TRUE every time.

But it doesn't. Running this query *usually* returns 1 row, but *sometimes* (quite frequently, more than 1 time out of 10) returns 0 rows. I have reproduced it with SQL Server 2008 on my system, and you can reproduce it on-line with the fiddle linked above (SQL Server 2014).

Looking at the execution plan reveals that the query analyzer apparently splits the condition into `s_guid < NEWID() OR s_guid > NEWID()`:

[image: query plan screenshot]

...which completely explains why it fails sometimes (if the first generated ID is smaller and the second one larger than the given ID).

Is SQL Server allowed to evaluate `A <> B` as `A < B OR A > B`, even if one of the expressions is non-deterministic? If yes, where is it documented? Or did we find a bug?

Interestingly, `AND NOT (s_guid = NEWID())` yields the same execution plan (and the same random result).

We found this issue when a developer wanted to optionally exclude a particular row and used:

```
s_guid <> ISNULL(@someParameter, NEWID())
```

as a "shortcut" for:

```
(@someParameter IS NULL OR s_guid <> @someParameter)
```

I am looking for documentation and/or confirmation of a bug. The code is not all that relevant so workarounds are not required.

Comment: It seems similar to this question: [Unexpected results with random numbers and join types](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/80374/unexpected-results-with-random-numbers-and-join-types)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> Is SQL Server allowed to evaluate `A <> B` as `A < B OR A > B`, even if one of the expressions is non-deterministic?

This is a somewhat controversial point, and the answer is a qualified "yes".

The best discussion I am aware of was given in answer to Itzik Ben-Gan's Connect bug report [Bug with NEWID and Table Expressions](https://web.archive.org/web/20160626085155/https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedbackdetail/view/350485/bug-with-newid-and-table-expressions), which was closed as won't fix. Connect has since been retired, so the link there is to a web archive. Sadly, a lot of useful material was lost (or made harder to find) by the demise of Connect. Anyway, the most useful quotes from Jim Hogg of Microsoft there are:

> This hits to the very heart of the issue - is optimization allowed to change a program's semantics? Ie: if a program yields certain answers, but runs slowly, is it legitimate for a Query Optimizer make that program run faster, yet also change the results given?
>
> Before shouting "NO!" (my own personal inclination too :-), consider: the good news is that, in 99% of cases, the answers ARE the same. So Query Optimization is a clear win. The bad news is that, if the query contains side-effecting code, then different plans CAN indeed yield different results. And NEWID() is one such side-effecting (non-deterministic) 'function' that exposes the difference. [Actually, if you experiment, you can devise others - for example, short-circuit evaluation of AND clauses: make the second clause throw an arithmetic divide-by-zero - different optimizations may execute that second clause BEFORE the first clause] This reflects Craig's explanation, elsewhere in this thread, that SqlServer does not guarantee when scalar operators are executed.
>
> So, we have a choice: if we want to guarantee a certain behavior in the presence of non-deterministic (side-effecting) code - so that results of JOINs, for example, follow the semantics of a nested-loop execution - then we can use appropriate OPTIONs to force that behavior - as UC points out. But the resulting code will run slow - that's the cost of, in effect, hobbling the Query Optimizer.
>
> All that said, we are moving the Query Optimizer in the direction of "as expected" behavior for NEWID() - trading off performance for "results as expected".

One example of the changing of behaviour in this regard over time is [NULLIF works incorrectly with non-deterministic functions such as RAND()](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32886796-nullif-works-incorrectly-with-non-deterministic-fu). There are also other similar cases using e.g. `COALESCE` with a subquery that can produce unexpected results, and which are also being addressed gradually.

Jim continues:

> Closing the loop . . . I've discussed this question with the Dev team. And eventually we have decided not to change current behavior, for the following reasons:
>
> 1) The optimizer does not guarantee timing or number of executions of scalar functions. This is a long-estabilished tenet. It's the fundamental 'leeway' tha allows the optimizer enough freedom to gain significant improvements in query-plan execution.
>
> 2) This "once-per-row behavior" is not a new issue, although it's not widely discussed. We started to tweak its behavior back in the Yukon release. But it's quite hard to pin down precisely, in all cases, exactly what it means! For example, does it a apply to interim rows calculated 'on the way' to the final result? - in which case it clearly depends on the plan chosen. Or does it apply only to the rows that will eventually appear in the completed result? - there's a nasty recursion going on here, as I'm sure you'll agree!
>
> 3) As I mentioned earlier, we default to "optimize performance" - which is good for 99% of cases. The 1% of cases where it might change results are fairly easy to spot - side-effecting 'functions' such as NEWID - and easy to 'fix' (trading perf, as a consequence). This default to "optimize performance" again, is long-established, and accepted. (Yes, it's not the stance chosen by compilers for conventional programming languages, but so be it).
>
> So, our recommendations are:
>
> a) Avoid reliance on non-guaranteed timing and number-of-executions semantics.
>   b) Avoid using NEWID() deep in table expressions.
>   c) Use OPTION to force a particular behavior (trading perf)
>
> Hope this explanation helps clarify our reasons for closing this bug as "won't fix".

---

> Interestingly, `AND NOT (s_guid = NEWID())` yields the same execution plan

This is a consequence of normalization, which happens very early during query compilation. Both expressions compile to exactly the same normalized form, so the same execution plan is produced.

Comment: In this case, if we want to force a particular plan which seems to avoid the issue, we can use WITH (FORCESCAN). To be certain, we should use a variable to store the result of NEWID() before executing the query.

Answer (score 11):

This is documented (sort of) here:

> The number of times that a function specified in a query is actually
>   executed can vary between execution plans built by the optimizer. An
>   example is a function invoked by a subquery in a WHERE clause. The
>   number of times the subquery and its function is executed can vary
>   with different access paths chosen by the optimizer.

[User-Defined Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/user-defined-functions?view=sql-server-2017)

This is not the only query form where the query plan will execute NEWID() multiple times and change the result.  This is confusing, but is actually critical for NEWID() to be useful for key generation and random sorting.

What's most confusing is that not all non-deterministic functions *actually* behave like this.  For instance RAND() and GETDATE() will execute only once per query.

Comment: Is there any blog post or similar that explains why/when the engine will convert "not equals" into a range ?

Comment: Not that I know of.  May be routine because `=`, `<`, and `>` can be efficiently evaluated against a BTree.

Answer (score 5):

For what it's worth, if you look at this [old SQL 92 standard document](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt), the requirements around inequality are described in section "`8.2  <comparison predicate>`" as follows:

> 1) Let X and Y be any two corresponding <row value constructor
>       element>s. Let XV and YV be the values represented by X and Y,
>       respectively.
>
> [...]
>
> ii) "X <> Y" is true if and only if XV and YV are not equal.
>
> [...]
>
> 7) Let Rx and Ry be the two <row value constructor>s of the <comparison predicate> and let RXi and RYi be the i-th <row value
>       constructor element>s of Rx and Ry, respectively. "Rx <comp op>
>       Ry" is true, false, or unknown as follows:
>
> [...]
>
> b) "x <> Ry" is true if and only if RXi <> RYi for some i.
>
> [...]
>
> h) "x <> Ry" is false if and only if "Rx = Ry" is true.

<sub>Note: I included 7b and 7h for completeness since they talk about `<>` comparison - I don't think comparison of row value constructors with multiple values is implemented in T-SQL, unless I'm just massively misunderstanding what this says - which is quite possible</sub>

This is a bunch of confusing garbage.  But if you want to keep dumpster diving...

I *think* that 1.ii is the item that applies in this scenario, since we're comparing the values of "row value constructor elements."

> **ii) "X <> Y" is true if and only if XV and YV are not equal.**

Basically it's saying `X <> Y` is true if the *values* represented by X and Y are not equal.  Since `X < Y OR X > Y` is a logically equivalent rewrite of that predicate, it's totally cool for the optimizer to use that.

The standard does not put any constraints on this definition related to the deterministic-ness (or whatever, you get it) of the row value constructor elements on either side of the `<>` comparison operator.  It's the responsibility of user code to deal with the fact that a value expression on one side might be non-deterministic.

Comment: I'll refarin from voting (up or down) but I'm not convinced. The quotes you provide mention **"value"**. My understanding is that comparison is between two values, one on each side. Not between two (or more) instantiations of a value on each side. Plus, the standard (at least the 92 you quote) does not mention at all non-deterministic functions. By a similar reasoning as yours, we can assume that a SQL product that complies with the standard does not provide any non-deterministic function but only those mentioned in the standard.

Comment: @yper thanks for the feedback!  I think your interpretation is definitely valid. This is the first time I've ever read that doc.  It's mentioning values in the context of the value represented by a "row value constructor," which elsewhere in the doc it says can be a scalar subquery (among many other things). The scalar subquery in particular seems like it could be non-deterministic. But I really don't know what I'm talking about =)